# Проверить, есть ли слово в строчке?

Tags: php

Есть такая вот строчка

$s = "/product/21"; Как проверить есть ли слов product в переменной $s

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php

Comment: @kff, ответы там на комментарии тянут.

Comment: `if(in_array('product', explode('/', $s))) {}`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку вам надо, как я понимаю,  не просто проверить наличие подстроки, а убедиться, что точно такой сегмент присутствует, я бы сделал так

```
$s = "/productc/21";
if(in_array('product', explode('/', $s))) { }
```